# XSD Verify attribute is set on only one element

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I have a pre-existing XML that I'm writing a XSD for.  The relevant section is basically:

```
<color a='1' default='true'>Red</foo>
<color a='2'>Yellow</foo>
<color a='3'>Blue</foo>
```

I want to validate that only one of the `foo` elements has an attribute `default='true'`.  Note the other elements can either have `default='false'` or not have it at all (in which case it defaults to `false`).

I tried to use a key but it doesn't work in the example above because there's multiple `default='false'` values which is not unique.

Can such validation be done with XSD 1.0?

(I can't change the XML format unfortunately.)

Answer (score 0):

> > Can such validation be done with XSD 1.0?

No. I suspect that XSD 1.1 could do it, but 1.0 defintely cannot.